# Google Sheet - It's possible to array sum function in the following condition?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Sample]

Would it be possible to use arrayformular for this condition?
Sum all the rows that PID are the same, the result should be as in the image.

I tried this code, but I think it's too long, and if the PID exceed over 20 rows, it would not work.

`=IF(A3<>A2,BJ3+IF(A3=A4,BJ4,0)+IF(A3=A5,BJ5,0)+IF(A3=A6,BJ6,0)+IF(A3=A7,BJ7,0)+IF(A3=A8,BJ8,0)+IF(A3=A9,BJ9,0)+IF(A3=A10,BJ10,0)+IF(A3=A11,BJ11,0)+IF(A3=A12,BJ12,0)+IF(A3=A13,BJ13,0)+IF(A3=A14,BJ14,0)+IF(A3=A15,BJ15,0)+IF(A3=A16,BJ16,0)+IF(A3=A17,BJ17,0)+IF(A3=A18,BJ18,0)+IF(A3=A19,BJ19,0)+IF(A3=A20,BJ20,0)+IF(A3=A21,BJ21,0)+IF(A3=A22,BJ22,0),0)`

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a table like this :

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |

You have an expected output of :

| ID | Value | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 15 |
| 1 | 10 | blank |
| 2 | 5 | 30 |
| 2 | 10 | blank |
| 2 | 15 | blank |

It is achievable with this formula (just drag it in your sum column) :

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIFS(B$2:B$12,A$2:A$12,A2))
```

It check if the ids are the same and then sum them, but only show them on the row where the id first appears

***Found it on google by searching [google sheets sum group by](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/sum-if-category-group/)***

Answer (score 1):

The following in C2 will generate the required answer without any copying-down required:

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A2:A),ifna(vlookup(row(A2:A),query({row(A2:B),A2:B},"select min(Col1),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col2"),2,false)),))
```

We are making a lookup table of grouped sums against the first row of each 'P#' group using QUERY, then using VLOOKUP to distribute the group sums to the first row in each group. Probably also doable using a SCAN/OFFSET combination as well, I think.